# Installing tensorflow version 1.4.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have cuda 8 installed in my machine. I found out tf version 1.4.0 is compatibile with cuda 8. how to install tensorflow-gpu version 1.4.0 with conda?

Comment: Have you tried `conda install tensorflow=1.4`? If yes, what went wrong?

Comment: tried conda install tensorflow=1.4, but solving environment failed

Comment: Please update your question with the output from conda. It matters why it failed.

Answer (score -1):

please remove 0 from 1.4.0 and try again

```
conda install tensorflow=1.4
```

Comment: It tries to install 1.4.1, not 1.4.0.